# How to exclude subtotal from woocommerce cart total?

Tags: woocommerce, cart

I am providing renting service online in my woocommerce website i want to charge only for refundable amount , but wants to also show the product amount, but while customer goes to view cart. there are products total shown in subtotal I want the final total amount in which the product total amount is excluded only refundable amount is included

General Cart:- $total=$subtotal+$refundable
I need :- $total=$refundable

How can i do that

Comment: please check www.instarents.com website and go to cart. there will product and refundable amount but the final total amount includes only refundable amount

Comment: **But please again,** could you try to clarify a little bit more your question, editing it (may be additionally giving a concrete example) and including in it your website link. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your refund as a custom fee. Please refer this [example](http://www.remicorson.com/add-custom-fee-to-woocommerce-cart-dynamically/)

```
    function woo_add_cart_fee() {
      global $woocommerce;  
      $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __('Refundable deposit', 'woocommerce'), -3750.00 ); 
// since its going to be refund we should add fee in negative value.  
// You can add the refund as fee in this hook
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```